# How to check for an empty get index?

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to reproduce PHP version easter egg (http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php).

As you can see, the get parameter has no name : `?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42`

I can check the URL with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but is there a way to check using only the `$_GET` array ?

I tried `$_GET['']` but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` give you when set `?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42` ?

Comment: No you can't! `$_GET` will be an empty array

Comment: This [the easter egg] appears to be PHP4 only easter egg, or at least, it doesn't work on various PHP websites

Comment: @Thamilan `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols `array(0) {}`. So I imagine I can only do it with something like $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?

Comment: Same with $_REQUEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET` is empty in this instance so no, it's not possible.

In addition to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` though.

```
[QUERY_STRING] => =PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of those solutions, but it isn't going well with my home made router. But as this is probably the only working solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DainisAbols you get the full thing which you can then parse

Answer (score 1):

This seemed interesting so I made a quick solution:

**Request** ?param1=asd&param3=123&=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42

**PHP**

```
function getFullRequest()
{
    $tmp = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $request = [];
    if (!empty($tmp) && is_array($tmp)) {
        foreach($tmp as $item) {
            $req = explode('=', $item);
            if (!empty($req) && is_array($req)) {
                $request[$req[0]] = $req[1];
            }
        }
    }

    return $request;
}

$request = getFullRequest();
var_dump($request);
```

**Result**

```
array (size=3)
  'param1' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  'param3' => string '123' (length=3)
  '' => string 'PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42' (length=39) // <- necessary value
```